# R: Aggregate data table with different functions in one step

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a data table `my_table` with numeric, character and date (`POSIXct`) columns. Now I need to `aggregate` it by date, where for each date the numeric columns shall be aggregated by `mean` and the character and date columns shall just have one of the available values (let's say the first occurence). I something like this:

```
  name          date    value
"test"    2018-04-04        1
"test"    2018-04-04        2
"test"    2018-04-05        8
"test"    2018-04-06        3
```

and I'd like to have this:

```
  name          date    value
"test"    2018-04-04      1.5
"test"    2018-04-05      8.0
"test"    2018-04-06      3.0
```

My approach has been this:

```
new_table <- aggregate(my_table, by=list(my_table$date), FUN=mean)
```

resulting in:

```
name       date   value
  NA  2018-04-04    1.5
  NA  2018-04-05    8.0
  NA  2018-04-06    3.0
```

and a bunch of warnings because `name` is not numeric. How can I tell the function to simply use one (or the first, I don't mind) of the occurences of `"test"` for `name` instead of `NA`?

---

To make things a bit harder: In my real case, there are actually a lot of columns that need to be aggregated either using mean (if they are numeric) or the first occurence (if they are `character` or `POSIXct`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own summarise function to do what you want according to the variables' class

```
my_table <- read.table(text =
                       "  name          date    value
                         test    2018-04-04        1
                         test    2018-04-04        2
                         test    2018-04-05        8
                         test    2018-04-06        3", 
                       header = T)

my_summarise <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x)
  else if(is.character(x)) x[1]
  else if(is.factor(x)) x[1]
  else if('POSIXct' %in% class(x)) x[1]
}

setDT(my_table)

my_table[, lapply(.SD, my_summarise), by = date]

#          date name value
# 1: 2018-04-04 test   1.5
# 2: 2018-04-05 test   8.0
# 3: 2018-04-06 test   3.0
```

Edit: That's actually not necessary. You can just do this to get the same result.

```
my_table[, .(name, mean(value)), by = date]
```

Comment: This works smoothly, but you have to do `library(lubridate)` first

Comment: I got the error message `Error in is.POSIXct(x) : could not find function "is.POSIXct"`, so I [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/)'ed that and found that I had to use the `lubridate` package. Which is fine, of course

Comment: For my real world case, your solution using a function actually is necessary. For this very basic example, it might be not, but I have a bunch of different columns which I just can't type all the time

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Base R solution using `aggregate`:

```
df <- transform(df, date = as.POSIXct(date))
aggregate(value ~ date + name, data = df, FUN = mean);
#date name value
#1 2018-04-04 test   1.5
#2 2018-04-05 test   8.0
#3 2018-04-06 test   3.0
```

If you have many columns that you don't want to list explicitly, you can use:

```
aggregate(value ~ ., data = df, FUN = mean);
```

The `.` means all columns in `df` *except* `value`.

### Method 2

`tidyverse` solution using `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>%
    group_by(date, name) %>%
    summarise(value = mean(value))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   date [?]
#  date                name  value
#  <dttm>              <fct> <dbl>
#1 2018-04-04 00:00:00 test   1.50
#2 2018-04-05 00:00:00 test   8.00
#3 2018-04-06 00:00:00 test   3.00
```

Your title is a bit misleading: why *"different functions"*? I assume you mean different columns. If you really *are* asking for aggregate to apply different functions, you can do e.g.

```
aggregate(value ~ date + name, data = df, FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)));
#        date name value.mean  value.sd
#1 2018-04-04 test  1.5000000 0.7071068
#2 2018-04-05 test  8.0000000        NA
#3 2018-04-06 test  3.0000000        NA
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  name          date    value
test    2018-04-04        1
test    2018-04-04        2
test    2018-04-05        8
test    2018-04-06        3", header = T)
```

Comment: I really like the one using Base R, but what if I can't name all the columns, in that case `date` and `name`? What if I have have more than 60 columns, of which I don't know their exact data type and order? Then I can't list them all like `value ~ date + name + col1 + col2 + ...`. Any way around that?

Comment: @s6hebern You can use `value ~ .`, where the dot `.` means all columns except `value`. `aggregate` is very versatile with the `formula` method. I've edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: This is all really great stuff (love the solution with `value ~ .`), but not yet what I need so far. Edited the question to hopefully make it a bit more clear. Aggregate does what it is supposed to do, I just need to get rid of the `NA`s. Can I use `na.action` for this somehow?

Comment: @s6hebern I can't see any change in your question. Did you perhaps forget to update the sample data? I advise against using `aggregate` the way you do; use the formula method and you won't get `NA`s for `name`.

Comment: I basically need it the other way round, maybe this was misleading. I need to aggregate all columns except for `date`, because this is the one the aggregation is based on. I think I just can't do it the way I thought about it and have to stick to @Renu's solution, but your examples gave me great insight into `aggregate` anyway, so thanks a lot for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact using a `data.table`, then here's the easy way to aggregate columns. Starting with a dataset that has multiple character and numeric columns:

```
library(data.table)

my_table <- data.table(
  name1  = letters[1:4],
  name2  = LETTERS[23:26],
  date   = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-04", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-05", "2018-04-06")),
  value1 = c(1, 2, 8, 3),
  value2 = c(9, 4, 2, 5)
)

my_table
#    name1 name2       date value1 value2
# 1:     a     W 2018-04-04      1      9
# 2:     b     X 2018-04-04      2      4
# 3:     c     Y 2018-04-05      8      2
# 4:     d     Z 2018-04-06      3      5
```

We can use the `Filter` function to create a new dataset with only numeric columns, then get the names of those columns. Afterwards, we'll do the same for character columns.

```
numeric_data <- Filter(is.numeric, my_table)
numeric_columns <- names(numeric_data)
numeric_columns
# [1] "value1" "value2"

character_data <- Filter(is.character, my_table)
character_columns <- names(character_data)
character_columns
# [1] "name1" "name2"
```

If you're worrying about this being inefficient for big data, don't. None of the data is actually being copied here.

```
address(my_table$name1)
# [1] "0000000004601058"
address(character_data$name1)
# [1] "0000000004601058"
```

Then we'll summarize the character and numeric values by the `date` column's values. The `j` part for a `data.table` can have any regular R code, which is executed inside each by-group. The `.SD` variable is the by-group's subset as a `data.table`, so we can use it to grab just the numeric or character columns.

```
my_table[
  ,
  {
    means <- lapply(
      X   = .SD[, numeric_columns, with = FALSE],
      FUN = mean
    )
    firsts <- .SD[1, character_columns, with = FALSE]
    append(firsts, means)
  },
  by = "date"
]
#          date name1 name2 value1 value2
# 1: 2018-04-04     a     W    1.5    6.5
# 2: 2018-04-05     c     Y    8.0    2.0
# 3: 2018-04-06     d     Z    3.0    5.0
```